# Z80 CPU and nested/reentrant NMI

Tags: assembly, z80, interrupt

According to multiple documentation sources, non-maskable interrupts (NMIs) can be nested (or reentrant) in a Z80 microprocessor.

This is, upon a `/NMI` signal pulse, the CPU will interrupt the current program by resetting `IFF1` to disable maskable interrupts, pushing the program counter in the stack and jumping to address 0x0066 to execute the interrupt service routine there.

The point is that a new `/NMI` signal pulse can interrupt the ongoing ISR before it ends with a `RETN` instruction. This is documented in [The Undocumented Z80 Documented](https://raine.1emulation.com/archive/dev/z80-documented.pdf) and confirmed in [other StackExchange questions](https://qstion.co/content-https-retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/22235/how-does-retn-return-from-nmi-on-the-z80-in-the-event-of-nested-nmi). When this happens, there is an odd case that, if permitted, would derive in an abnormal situation.

If maskable interrupts were enabled before the NMI was accepted, the first invocation of the ISR will execute with `IFF1` reset and `IFF2` set. This is the well-known mechanism to restore `IFF1` from `IFF2` by `RETN` instruction when ISR terminates, so the user-defined interruption config is honored.

When the second `/NMI` pulse is detected before `RETN` takes place, a new NMI is accepted by the CPU. It will perform exactly the same procedure as the outer ISR: reset `IFF1`, push `PC` in the stack and jump to 0x0066.

Now let's say the inner ISR ends with a `RETN` instruction without any further NMI reentrance. This will copy `IFF2` into `IFF1`, pop the `PC` from the stack, and continue with the execution of the ISR of the outer NMI. As maskable interrupts were enabled since the very beginning,  this will effectively enable those interrupts. And the ISR of the outer NMI will execute such that **it can be interrupted again by a maskable interrupt**.

In other words, nested or reentrant NMIs can derive in situations where maskable interrupts are enabled, and a `/INT` signal can interrupt the execution of a NMI. This is equivalent to putting a `EI` instruction in the code of the NMI service routine.

After this, I am not sure if there is something I am not considering, or just that this is a flaw of the original design of the CPU. I checked the source code of a few Z80 emulators ([MAME](https://github.com/mamedev/mame/blob/master/src/devices/cpu/z80/z80.cpp) included), and all them operate as I am assuming. If that's how the things work, is `/NMI` something that have to be used very carefully? Do designers have to consider this and ensure `/NMI` cannot have multiple pulses? Or perhaps it is totally OK to have maskable interrupts interrupting NMIs? Am I exaggerating the situation then?

Comment: Before going into any details, I assume you are aware that an NMI is only intended as a last resort to allow interruption in unusual/critical situations? They are kind of a 'hack' to still allow interruption when incidents past regular operation happen. They essentially offer this bypassing all regular mechanics - and as usual when bypassing safety measures, the risks are all to be accounted for by the implementor.

Comment: That was my impression. In my mind, the perfect example for NMI is the parity check of a memory system. If parity detects an error, it could trigger a NMI to stop the world and inform the user that some RAM chip have to be replaced. However, I read recently that Sega Master System used the NMI to handle the pause button. Which is far from that last resort interruption.

Comment: It all depends on the use case of a system. An NMI is reserved for well defined situations - either because they are dead end anyway (like a memory fault or a power outage) or because the system is defined to work that way. A general purpose computer will be of the first kind, while an embedded system might be of the later. Game consoles are as well embedded systems. Every interaction within is well adjusted to cooperate in a non harmful way. In such an environment everything can be used as one likes, as all components are adjusted to work with it.

Comment: AlvaroPolo, a good and well-presented question. NMIs are an essential and well-structured part of a microprocessor like a Z80, 6502, 6809 etc. Any running program has the capability to disable maskable interrupts with one inappropriate or crash-executed execution of a DI-type instruction so the system designer must be provided with a mechanism that cannot be blocked in this way. NMIs and INTs/IRQs are well-balanced options that system designers must select between and use with care, like many things. Same as maximum interrupt repetition, which you've uncovered an interesting Z80 aspect of.

Answer (score 4):

It would cost a single flip-flop to prevent re-entering NMI handler, or at least the greatest part of it. The flip-flop output pin is routed to the `/NMI` pin, flip-flop `reset` is to actual NMI pulse source. The `set` pin would be then strobed programmatically (for example, doing `out` to a dedicated IO-port), as the last instruction before `RETN`.

This way, there is only a small chance of re-entering the NMI handler before `RETN` executes and in *most* cases re-entering would not do any harm.

More sophisticated measures could be counting `/M1` cycles after triggering the abovementioned dedicated port -- so that actual NMI de-assertion would be done exactly as `RETN` has fully executed. This kind of NMI handling was actually done by me in "ZX-Evolution" ZX Spectrum clone.

The real problem of NMI in Z80 is the practical inability for an external observer to determine when Z80 actually starts to execute NMI ('start' here is when Z80 begins pushing return address). Given such an indication (in a way as it exists for maskable interrupt, which begins with `/IORQ`+`/M1` strobation), one can enter NMI handler fully preserving CPU *and* memory state (by routing return address push to the dedicated registers instead of memory).

My current way of thinking as how to achieve that includes looking for every Z80 M1 and RD/WR cycle it executes and keeping a state of whether Z80 finishes executing each instruction, so that an unexpected double push after `/NMI` is toggled would be the thing.

Comment: In most cases, rather than using a dedicated flip flop to prevent re-entrant NMI, one would design whatever device would trigger an NMI in such a way as to ensure that it will only trigger once.

Comment: Only triggering NMI once a lifetime of device (meaning lifetime since Z80 and devices were reset) does not seem like an universal approach. Once multiple NMI events each from independent device are wanted, the re-entry problem returns.

Comment: I meant "only trigger in non-reentrant fashion".  If the Z80 intended NMI to be used only for fatal conditions, it wouldn't need the RETN instruction and its associated latch.  It's common for systems to e.g. have an NMI circuit that is disabled by reset, and will never generate pulses that are less than some distance apart, and for that NMI to be combined with a service routine whose execution time is always much shorter than the time between non-maskable interrupt events.

Comment: What was intended in 1976 is of less use today for retro-enthusiasts. Nowadays it is 'what we can achieve by abusing it' :)

Comment: My point was that there's nothing wrong with using NMI in situations where a system is operating normally, and is expected to continue to do so, with the proviso that external hardware must only assert NMI at times when a program is prepared for that to happen.  How external hardware would know that the program is prepared for an NMI would depend upon the application.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. However, the circuit design of a well defined NMI is out of the scope of this question. What I wanted to know is if NMIs can be interrupted by INTs in the case of having nested/reentrant non-maskable interrupts, according to the sequence of actions described in the question body. As it seems in the case of some implementations such as Sega Master System.

Comment: How then "Do designers have to consider this and ensure /NMI cannot have multiple pulses" still *in* the scope of the question? My answer is exactly about it.

Comment: Oh, I think it was clear from that question that I was interested in whether or not designers have to take this inconsistency in consideration. But not how, which is what your response explains. But please, do not take this as a blame. I appreciate your response. It is just I was mainly interested in finding out if this is how the Z80 actually works and what is the intention behind it.

Comment: It is obvious for me that the designers made exactly what they did. All your assumptions and deductions about NMI are actually right, and the only thing one can do here is to live with it :) Either by working around in software or in hardware (or both).